# How to automatically set parameters from array

Tags: android, loops

I'm pretty new in java and I don't know how to syntax that part of the code.
I have an array passed from a server with headers - key and value.. example User-agent => "Mozilla la la lala".
That array is with an unlimited parameters.
Which means I need some loop to add all of them.
I need to set them in the httpget object.

```
get.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36");
```

It must be something like

```
foreach($parameters as $key => $value){ $get.setHeader($key,$value);}
```

Which is on php but I need that in java

Answer (score 0):

As you are already having the array of headers, please do it as given below:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com");

    Header[] headers = //put your headers array here
    for (Header header : headers) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + header.getName() 
              + " ,Value : " + header.getValue());

    //Here you can set the headers to http request 
     httpGet.setHeader(header.getName(), header.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: I'm not getting headers from a connection.I'm setting them for a new one.HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            ctx.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(server);

            get.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36");HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get,ctx);

Comment: If i am getting you, you are already having list of headers and you just want to put them in the http request. Please correct if i am wrong,

Answer (score 0):

If you have a String array passed from the server with the values inside it always formatted as: {"key", "value", "key", "value"} then you can perform a simple for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (myArray.length - 1); i += 2){

            get.setHeader(myArray[i], myArray[i + 1]);

}
```